# How to properly deploy a google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, web-deployment

I am have created a form that submits to a spreadsheet, and I've created a script that should display the submissions on to an html page. After hitting the deploy button and adding the link into my google site. It display's an out put from an older script.

According to the tutorial I have been following I dont think I am missing a step here for updating scrips

```
 1. save script
 2. click deploy as web app
 3. copy link in the model box and submit it
 4. add link inside the insert script modal on my google site
 5. refresh the page
```

Is there a better way to do this? How can I debug this?

Sorry I am very new to apps script
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to save a version of your script. When you deploy (or re-deploy) your App you can [choose what version to use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps?hl=fr-FR#deploying). The "manage versions" option is in the file menu.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! how do i get that drop down to display a second number because it only shows "1" ?

Comment: Sorry, i dont think my comment was clear, I can see this but when i click on the drop down menu for project version, there is no option to change the version number from 1 to 2

Comment: Sorry, i dont think my comment was clear, I can see this but when i click on the drop down menu for project version, there is no option to change the version number from 1 to 2

Comment: You have to create a new version . To do that go to/file/manage version/create a new version ... then go back to the deploy menu and the new version number will be available

Answer (score 0):

There are two version of the script that are deployed.

One is deployed using the process of publishing, where you select the version number or the project, these are a available for selection one a version has been saved.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_versions

In between two versions, as you develop, you may want to see the development version on your script, in that case you need to it another url in the browser.

This url will return the lastest saved version of your script

```
script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz1Q5MI...Kf8EvFitCGW6sAQcs0QnmfP3Pw6/exec
```

This url will return your current development version, this is great for evolutionary code

```
script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz1Q5MI...Kf8EvFitCGW6sAQcs0QnmfP3Pw/dev
```